# Undefined Anonymous Function With JQuery Accordion in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

So I've gotten two different Jquery plugins integrated into my Wordpress theme, but for some reason, when trying to use JQuery's built in accordion feature I've been getting an "undefined is not a function - anonymous function" error in the chrome console. Here is my functions.php code for the registering the jquery script:

```
function issue_accordion() {
wp_enqueue_script ( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script ('jquery', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/jquery.js' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jqueryui' );
    wp_register_script('accordion', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/jquery-ui.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script( 'accordion');
    wp_register_style('accordioncss', get_template_directory_uri(). '/jquery-ui.css');
    wp_register_style('accordioncss', get_template_directory_uri(). '/jquery-ui.theme.css');
    wp_register_style('accordioncss', get_template_directory_uri(). '/jquery-ui.structure.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('accordioncss');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'issue_accordion');
```

Then this is me calling the script in the .php file:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery('#accordion').accordion();
</script>
```

A link to the actual page is here:

http://www.azletconsulting.com/?page_id=13

I can't figure out what the issue would be since the api documentation says the function is .accordion() and I'm properly implementing the no-conflict jquery wordpress method in the same manner as I did with the other two jquery scripts I'm using on the site.

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a built-in accordion function. jQuery **UI** does.

Comment: So I got the Accordion function to work, but now it won't allow me to open or close any tabs.

http://www.azletconsulting.com/?page_id=13

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, you're calling `jQuery('#accordion').accordion();` before the plugin has been instantiated. This is what's throwing the `undefined` error.

Comment: Shouldn't WP be enqueuing my jquery-ui files in the header though and my script is placed in the body?

Comment: I don't know much about the inner workings of Wordpress, but if you view your source the accordion plugin is being instantiated at the bottom of your page, before the `</body>` tag, and well below where you're calling `.accordion()`.

I imagine the fix is simply moving some furniture around in your theme.

Comment: So I just dropped this in the header.php file: and it seems to have fixed the issue.
<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?>
<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core'); ?>
<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-accordion'); ?>

Comment: Good deal! Though, I would highly suggest putting most, if not all, of your `<script>`'s at the bottom your `<body>` tag. As discussed [in this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24070373/4052381) :)

Comment: Now the issue I'm having is that the actual accordion menu isn't animating, and I can't go through the different options. It's just stuck open/closed. I will definitely take a look at that answer about JS and the body tag post though. This is the first time I'm incorporating JS into a theme.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which accordion plugin are you using? Also, on your live site you're using the `#accordion` ID as a selector to instantiate the `.accordion()` functionality but that ID doesn't exist in your DOM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74762/discussion-between-baroti-and-tyler-kelley).